# How to search for things within this year with Google?

Tags: google-search

How to search on Google for things within one year?

I found that when we want to find some tutorials, they are outdated and not useful anymore. So I want to restrict the search within one year.

Answer (score 5):

You can use advanced search in google, and provide the Last Updated field as "Past year".

Alternatively, you can use "Search Tools"

[image]

Hope, that will help.